# Form submission makes div dissapear

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with questions. There are 2 problems when I submit:

1. preventDefault changes the question but doesn't accept the next
   answer
2. no preventDefault accepts the answer, goes to the next question but
   doesn't show the "next" button.

   ```
       var questions = [
           ["question 1", "answer 1", "hint"],
           ["question 2", "answer 2", "hint" ]
       ];

    //div with first question
    <div></div>


   //answer to question    
   var questionAnswer = questions[0][1];

    $('#input').on("keypress", function(e){
       if(e.keyCode === 13){
           var inputAnswer = $('input[name="answer"]').val().toUpperCase();
           if(inputAnswer === questionAnswer){
               $("#next").append("Next Question");
           }
           else{
               $("form").effect("shake");
           }
           $('form').trigger('reset'); 
           e.preventDefault();
       }
   });

   //Next question button
   <div id="next"></div>

   //Magically changes question & answer for next question
   $(document).on("click", "#next", function(){
   function randomQuestion(){
   return questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];
   };
   });
   ```

Comment: Do you have a loop or something? How should it work?

Comment: I have been trying to go through the array and randomly selecting a question.

Comment: So if you select ONE random question, what would 'next question' mean?

Comment: The part that says "next question" is for a button that goes through the questions array and picks a question again.

Comment: So it can choose a repeated question again

Comment: Yes, questions can repeat again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//init first random question
var randomQuestionNo = getRandomQuestion(questions.length);
$('#questions_div').text("Question: " + questions[randomQuestionNo][0]);
$('#answer_input').data("question_no", randomQuestionNo);
$('#hiddenNext_btn').hide();

//Textfield
$('#answer_input').on("keypress", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        var inputAnswer = $('#answer_input').val().toUpperCase();
        if(inputAnswer === questions[$(this).data("question_no")][1]){
            $('#hiddenNext_btn').show();                
        } else {
            $("#quiz_form").effect("shake");
            $('#answer_input').val("");
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

//Next button
$('#hiddenNext_btn').click(function() {
    randomQuestionNo = getRandomQuestion(questions.length);
    $('#answer_input').val("");
    $('#questions_div').text("Question: " + questions[randomQuestionNo][0]);
    $('#answer_input').data("question_no", randomQuestionNo);   
    $(this).hide();
});
```

The random part is here

```
function getRandomQuestion(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*max);
}
```

I have built a demo for you, maybe it is not a best solution, but still hope this can help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/sing0920/Rp494/

Comment: If possible, an update of it being random would be wonderful.

Comment: Question that has been asked will it appears again?

Comment: Yes, it can appear again.